# mysql workbench auto_increment

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. При импортировании таблицы в mysql с помощью workbench возникла проблема.Суть в том, что id ,заданный как auto increment не заполняется после импортирования таблицы.

Вот скриншот , описывающий, как задана таблица и сам id.

[image: Вот скриншот , описывающий, как задана таблица и сам id.]

А вот что происходит при импортировании таблицы, id не заполняется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?
Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый и я не заметил чего-то очевидного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно у вас. При экспорте Workbench сгенерирует для каждой таблицы INSERT запросы вида

```
INSERT INTO `testdb`.`tabledb` (`id`, `column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 6, 4, '32424');
INSERT INTO `testdb`.`tabledb` (`id`, `column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 6, 4, '32424');
INSERT INTO `testdb`.`tabledb` (`id`, `column1`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 6, 4, '32424');
```

Если сгенерированный скрипт импортировать, например, в phpMyAdmin, то в поле id вместо **DEFAULT** будет значение, полученное автоинкрементом (главное чтобы поле id было автоинкрементным)

Comment: Хм, извините, но может я неправильно понял. Просто когда я отправляю изменения ( то есть импортированную таблицу) в свою локальную бд и просматриваю её через консоль , то там так же не отображается id. К тому же в приложенном мной скриншоте я как раз потому и поставил id в конец чтобы продемонстрировать проблему, потому что если столбец id поставить вначале,то первый столбец импортируемой таблицы занимает его ( хотя как я понял из ваших слов он должен оставаться пустым, а вывод импортируемой таблицы должен начинаться со второго столбца).

Comment: а на счёт сгенерированного запроса ( сейчас я уже закрыл виртуальную машину, посмотрю завтра если надо будет уточнить). То там на место id генерируется не 'DEFAULT' , а пустая строка, то есть ''.